# I accidentally sent BUSD oken to a random token contract. Can I get it back?

Tags: bsc, bscscan

On Binance Smart Chain - Instead of transferring my BUSD token to my wallet, I accidentally sent it to 'CougarSwap: CGS Token' contract itself (the contract, with source code, is https://bscscan.com/address/0x26d88b1e61e22da3f1a1ba95a1ba278f6fcef00b).

Would the contract creator be able to send it back to me? Is there a way to check this?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot retrieve your BUSD tokens because don't exist a `withdraw()` function. Furthermore, contract creator cannot be able to resend you BUSD Token because he don't have the property to access and transfer token from smart contract balance.